# Warnings found during shrinking, please use -dontwarn or -ignorewarnings to suppress them

Tags: android, proguard

How to solve this error? We tried clean and rebuild , restart android studio and no use.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithAndroidGradleClassShrinkerForDebug'.

> Warnings found during shrinking, please use -dontwarn or -ignorewarnings to suppress them.

we are using this lib

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    compile('com.alibaba.android:ultraviewpager:1.0.6.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6') {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }
    compile 'com.littlechoc.cornerlabel:cornerlabel:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.4'
    compile 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.5.5'
    compile 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.5.5'
    implementation 'com.muddzdev:styleabletoast:2.0.2'
    compile 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2'
    compile 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.+'
    // base library
    //slider
    compile 'com.ss.bannerslider:bannerslider:1.8.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.2.7'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.4'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.2.6'
    compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.+'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.8.0'
    compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'
    compile 'at.blogc:expandabletextview:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.joanzapata.iconify:android-iconify-fontawesome:2.1.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.sackcentury:shinebutton:0.2.0'
    compile 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
    implementation("com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:6.0.7@aar") {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.plattysoft.leonids:LeonidsLib:1.3.2'
    //permission asking module
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:4.2.0'
```

//chat
    compile 'com.github.timigod:android-chat-ui:v0.1.3'

```
compile 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.1'
```

//    compile 'com.github.vipulasri:timelineview:1.0.5'
    compile 'com.ernestoyaquello.stepperform:vertical-stepper-form:0.9.9'

```
//multiple image picjer is not working
```

// compile 'net.alhazmy13.MediaPicker:libary:2.4.0'

```
implementation 'com.github.esafirm.android-image-picker:imagepicker:1.12.0'
// for experimental rx picker
//implementation 'com.github.esafirm.android-image-picker:rximagepicker:1.12.0'
// If you have a problem with Glide, please use the same Glide version or simply open an issue
```

// implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.5.0'
    //annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'

```
compile 'com.commit451:PhotoView:1.2.4'
compile 'com.isseiaoki:simplecropview:1.0.13'
compile 'com.yongchun:com.yongchun.imageselector:1.1.0'
```

error

```
com/yongchun/library/view/ImagePreviewFragment references unknown class: com/bumptech/glide/BitmapTypeRequest
com/yongchun/library/adapter/ImageFolderAdapter references unknown class: com/bumptech/glide/DrawableRequestBuilder
com/yongchun/library/adapter/ImageFolderAdapter references unknown class: com/bumptech/glide/DrawableTypeRequest
com/yongchun/library/adapter/ImageListAdapter references unknown class: com/bumptech/glide/DrawableRequestBuilder
com/yongchun/library/adapter/ImageListAdapter references unknown class: com/bumptech/glide/DrawableTypeRequest
com/yongchun/library/adapter/ImageListAdapter.onBindViewHolder:(Landroid/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView$ViewHolder;I)V references unknown class member: com/bumptech/glide/RequestManager.load:(Ljava/io/File;)Lcom/bumptech/glide/DrawableTypeRequest;
com/yongchun/library/view/ImagePreviewFragment.onCreateView:(Landroid/view/LayoutInflater;Landroid/view/ViewGroup;Landroid/os/Bundle;)Landroid/view/View; references unknown class member: com/bumptech/glide/RequestManager.load:(Ljava/io/File;)Lcom/bumptech/glide/DrawableTypeRequest;
com/yongchun/library/view/ImagePreviewFragment references unknown class: com/bumptech/glide/DrawableTypeRequest
com/yongchun/library/adapter/ImageFolderAdapter.onBindViewHolder:(Lcom/yongchun/library/adapter/ImageFolderAdapter$ViewHolder;I)V references unknown class member: com/bumptech/glide/RequestManager.load:(Ljava/io/File;)Lcom/bumptech/glide/DrawableTypeRequest;
com/yongchun/library/view/ImagePreviewFragment$1 references unknown class: com/bumptech/glide/request/animation/GlideAnimation
:app:transformClassesWithAndroidGradleClassShrinkerForDebug FAILED
:app:buildInfoGeneratorDebug

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithAndroidGradleClassShrinkerForDebug'.
> Warnings found during shrinking, please use -dontwarn or -ignorewarnings to suppress them.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 19s
```

Comment: `use -dontwarn or -ignorewarnings to suppress them.` as it says.

Comment: where to add that line?

Comment: in here progurad-rule.pro ?

Comment: for which  lib we need to add it ?

Comment: `in here progurad-rule.pro` check which proguard rules file you use in your build type. `for which lib we need to add it` depends on the warnings you get. You didn't show them. In general each lib requires it's own proguard rules

Comment: error is only showing like this and how to identify which lib required this "Warnings found during shrinking, please use -dontwarn or -ignorewarnings to suppress them"

Comment: check the build log, it should show the `Warnings` which were `found during shrinking`

Comment: updated in question details please check

Comment: ok, unfortunately `com.yongchun.imageselector` does not explain what needs to be added to proguard rules for fis library. Try adding `-dontwarn com.yongchun.**` to proguard rules

Comment: thank you . it is now working sucessfully

Comment: I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes (actually most times) Proguard is paranoid, because it can't find some references. Usually, its warnings can be just ignored in cases where you are sure that you implemented it correctly.

To fix your error, you need to ignore the `com.yongchun` warnings like this:
Add to your Proguard rules `-dontwarn com.yongchun.**`